# How to add a new device to an ad-hoc distribution profile in the new (2013) Apple developer console?

Tags: device, profile, provisioning, adhoc

I tried to modify (edit) my ad-hoc distribution profile and ad a new device for testing. But in the new Apple Developer Console there is no option to new devices ! Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to do so, was by adding a new provisioning profile (under provisioning profiles click on the "+" in the top right corner).

Thus, to add a device to an existing provisioning profile, I deleted the current profile and created a new one with the same name.

Comment: That worked for me, however, looks like every time you need to add a device, you need to re-create a new ad hoc profile. Sounds like a bug to me.